# emacs: find-file-at-point -- how to escape spaces in filepath?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I am new to emacs... when using ffap to open the file under cursor, I noticed that ffap does not recognize spaces in the file path. Tried to escape the space (just like in vim), but it seems not work.

I hate spaces in filename as well, but we just don't have control sometimes. Wonder if there any nice emacsian way of handling such cases?

Did some search and found that the cygwin emacs has a patch to deal with spaces in the path, yet it is not available to the linux emacs.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. Emacs 25.2.

Comment: Hmm, it does not work for me. I am using emacs 25.1. Have you tried the space in the middle of the path, like: `/home/user/share/Google Drive/folder/file.txt`?

Comment: Alas, it doesn't. It stops either on `.../Google Drive/` or on `.../Google Drive/folder/` depending on cursor location.

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce it and I think it is a bug, I opened an issue on github: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9743

Comment: :). This is not a spacemacs issue but rather an ffap one.

Comment: sent a bug report to the emacs devs, let's see what they say